# how to create child tables from parent tables using parent data

Tags: mysql

I am trying to achieve below in mysql. I want to insert past 5 months data from history table into newly created child table.
I have history table with 3 columns (item_code, price, create_date). Using this history table I want to create new child table which has 4 columns (item_code, price, price_start_period, price_end_period)

Ex. History Table:

[Item_code]    [price]      [create_date]
----------   ---------   -----------

101          $20       3/1/2013 1PM

101          $20       3/1/2013 2PM

101          $20       3/1/2013 2.20PM

101          $25       3/1/2013 4PM

101          $30       3/2/2013 8AM

102          $23       3/1/2013 7AM

101          $30       3/3/2013 1AM

101          $30       3/5/2013 8PM

102          $40       3/2/2013 5PM

102          $40       3/2/2013 6PM

102          $40       3/3/2013 7PM

Result table (new child table using above data):

[Item_code]    [Price]    [Price_start_period ]   [Price_end_period]
----------   ------     ------------------    -----------------
101           $20       3/1/2013 1PM            3/1/2013 4PM

101           $25       3/1/2013 4PM            3/2/2013 8AM

101           $30       3/2/2013 8AM            null (means for 101 current price is 30$)

102           $23       3/1/2013 7AM            3/2/2013 5PM

102           $40       3/2/2013 5PM            null

So basically, I would like to find out what is the interval for different prices for an item_code.

How can I create this resulting table using mysql?

THanks in advance,
- R

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
insert into new_table
select item_code, price, min(create_date), max(create_date)
from history_table
group by 1,2
```